# Fullscreen/Immersive mode lost when application come back to foreground

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

I'm trying to add Immersive mode on my Android application using OpenGL ES. Everything work, but when I put my application to background and I come back in, my application lose is full screen status (Navigation bar is back).

Here is my method to put application to fullscreen/immersive mode (I call it from onCreate in my MainActivity):

```
private void setFullScreen() 
{   
    int uiOptions = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        uiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        uiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
        uiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    }

    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

How can I handle that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Call `setFullScreen()` in your `onResume()` method instead of `onCreate()`.

Comment: It work better! But when I touch the screen, the navigation bar come back.

Comment: Are you testing on a KitKat device?

Comment: Yes, A Nexus 4 with android 4.4.2